# Data filtering VS Sampling Process

Tags: heading

I am writing on a write up of how i obtained my sample from a large population. But I am contemplating whether I should categorize them under 'data filtering' or a 'sampling process'.

Any idea what is the difference between 'data filtering' and 'sampling process'?

Comment: I suspect this might be more suited to Cross Validated ---> http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: filtering data involves throwing out samples you've collected.  I assume you are talking about just collecting samples from a "random?" subset of the population?

Comment: @Jim i am 'removing' data from a population due to for instance missing variables..